# Problema al arrancar un docker por falta de MongoDB libmongocrypt dll (netcore/linux)

Tags: mongodb, docker, .net-core

Estoy usando VS para MAC 8.9.2
Actualmente estoy desarrollando una architectura desde cero, usando net core 3.1, como  parte de esta architectura estor escribiendo un adaptador para mongodb, usando el nuget MongoDB.Driver 2.12.0

Cuando ejecuto en local el servicio o los test unitarios, todo  funciona perfectamente. Pero cuando puclico (el ensamblado mongodb.libmongocryp.dll esta incluido) los runtimes a un contenedor de docker con linux, esta imagen no arranca y da el siguiente error:

> Error:   An assembly specified in the application dependencies
> manifest (arn.worker.services.deps.json) was not found:
> package: 'MongoDB.LibMongocrypt', version: '1.2.0'
> path: 'lib/netstandard2.1/MongoDB.LibMongocrypt.dll'

Este servicio ha estado funcionando perfectamente durante semanas, y no se si por alguna actulizacion del driver de mongo, ha dejado de funcionar,

mas info, son 2 proyectos

- el servicio principal
- componentes de tipo adaptador (nuget mongodb.driver)

mi pregunta es, porque net core me esta dando este error? si el fichero que indica esta incluido en el directorio de publicacion,

Contenido de la carpeta de publicación:
[image: Contenido de la carpeta de publicación]

Alguna idea? Preguntadme si necesitais mas datos,
gracias

Comment: Solved, there is a new mongodb.driver version 2.12.1 that solves the mystery, thanks to all, take care of yourself

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, hay una nueva version del driver mongodb.driver 2.12.1 que resuelve el problema, gracias a todos, cuidaros,